# How can I change path of executeble in QCreator?

Tags: qt5

I have installed an Ubuntu 16.04, an on top of it, a Qt 5.9.5.
The project builds apparenly fine, the built binaries are there in subdirectory ./buid/bin, but when Qt running through them through the IDE, it looks at . subdirectory.
How can I direct it to the right subdirectory?

Comment: What does _Qt running through them_ mean?

Comment: Sorry, when I wanted to debug, QCreator said there was no executable. The executable is there in 'project/build/bin', but QCreator looks for it in 'project'. If I comment out in my CMakeList.txt the line set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"), the executables go in the project directory, everything works fine. I guess I have some missing 'SET' in my cmakelist.txt file. Last time I generated system more than two years ago, and I did not have similar problems.